# Creating an NSArray to represent values that include nil

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsarray, variadic-functions

I have data source method which asks for an `NSArray` of numbers; some of them could be `nil`, but I need to return every value anyways.

The method might look like this:

```
- (NSArray *)configurationValues:(Configuration *)configuration {
  ....  
  return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:value1, value2, value3, value4, nil];
}
```

If the `value3` is `nil`, I have to return {2, 3, (object is nil), 3}.

Off course I'm getting exceptions because I *can't insert a `nil` object*.

What I can do is check every object and insert some dummy number or `NSNull`, but this to me seems like boilerplate, and not really elegant.

I'm trying to create a category for `NSArray` which would replace all `nil` values with something else to avoid the exceptions:

```
@implementation NSArray (Nullable)

+ (instancetype)arrayWithObjectsSafe:(id)firstObj, ... {
    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];
    va_list args;
    id  object;

    va_start(args, firstObj);

    while((object = va_arg(args, id))) {
        if (object) {
            [array addObject:object];
        } else {
            // Insert dummy element // stuck here
            [array addObject:[NSNull null]];
        }
        NSLog(@"OBJECT %@", object);

    }

    va_end(args);
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:array];
}
@end
```

I'm not really familiar with variadic methods, and I'm stuck here because the `while` loop skips the `nil` value, so the final array contains only the elements before the `nil`.

Can I fix this, or is there an existing way for `NSArray` to not throw an exception when trying to insert `nil` object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code fails simply because you are using `nil` as both your end of arguments marker and as one of the arguments. Just use a different end of arguments marker. For example you can define:

```
const id END_MARKER (__bridge id)(void *)-1;
```

to define another constant rather like `nil` (which has the value 0). Change your loop to:

```
while((object = va_arg(args, id)) != END_MARKER)
```

and your call to:

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:value1, value2, value3, value4, END_MARKER];
```

and your code works.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's not going to work. If there is a NULL in your list of objects, your loop will take that as the end of the list. It will not crash, but it also won't add an [NSNull null].

The check is as easy as value1 ?: [NSNull null] instead of value1.